# Saving values during an R shiny session

Tags: r, shiny

I have a single-cell gene x cell expression data that I'd like to explore using a `shiny` `app`. The cells come from samples and are clustered according to a prior clustering run.

Here is a toy example data set:

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(plotly))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(shiny))
set.seed(1)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(1000*1000),nrow=1000,dimnames = list(paste0("gene",1:1000),paste0("cell",1:1000)))
meta.df <- data.frame(cell=colnames(mat),
                      sample=sample(paste0("sample",1:10),1000,replace=T),
                      cluster=sample(paste0("cluster",1:5),200,replace=T),
                      stringsAsFactors = F)
```

There are two functionalities that I'd like to enable:

1. View the `tSNE` 2D embedding of the entire data allowing to choose a gene where the points in the `tSNE` `2D` embedding `scatter` `plot` will be colored by its expression values.
2. Be able to select a specific set of genes and clusters and/or samples on which tSNE will be re-run, and again view this 2D embedding coloring the points according to the expression levels of a chosen gene (in this case obviously the selection options is subsetted to be one of the selected genes).

Here's the `tSNE` embedding on all the data:

```
all.data.tsne.df <- data.frame(Rtsne::Rtsne(t(mat))$Y) %>%
  rename(tSNE1=X1,tSNE2=X2) %>% cbind(meta.df)
```

For the second functionality, since one might like to color code many genes using the same `tSNE` embedding, and since a `Rtsne` run can take a while to run, I thought I'd save any gene and cell subset `tSNE` embedding in a list named by the chosen genes and cells, and always check if this subset already exists before running the `Rtsne` on it.

So at the top of the `shiny` code I create the options for subsetting samples and clusters and an empty `tSNE` `list`:

```
samples <- c("all",unique(meta.df$sample))
samples.choices <- 1:length(samples)
names(samples.choices) <- samples
clusters <- c("all",unique(meta.df$cluster))
clusters.choices <- 1:length(clusters)
names(clusters.choices) <- clusters
color.vec <- c("lightgray","darkred")
subset.tsne.map <- NULL
```

Here's my `server` code:

```
server <- function(input, output)
{
  chosen.samples <- reactive({
    validate(
      need(input$samples.choice != "",'Please choose at least one of the sample checkboxes')
    )
    samples.choice <- input$samples.choice
    if("all" %in% samples.choice) samples.choice <- samples[-which(samples == "all")]
    samples.choice
  })

  chosen.clusters <- reactive({
    validate(
      need(input$clusters.choice != "",'Please choose at least one of the cluster checkboxes')
    )
    clusters.choice <- input$clusters.choice
    if("all" %in% clusters.choice) clusters.choice <- clusters[-which(clusters == "all")]
    clusters.choice
  })

  output$gene <- renderUI({
    if(input$plotType == "Gene-Subset tSNE"){
      selectInput("gene", "Color by Gene", choices = unique(input$subset.genes))
    } else{
      selectInput("gene", "Color by Gene", choices = rownames(mat))
    }
  })

  scatter.plot <- reactive({
    if(!is.null(input$gene)){
      row.idx <- which(rownames(mat) == input$gene)
      col.idx <- which(colnames(mat) %in% filter(meta.df,cluster %in% chosen.clusters(),sample %in% chosen.samples())$cell)
      #col.idx <- which(colnames(mat) %in% filter(meta.df,cluster %in% "cluster4",sample %in% unique(meta.df$sample))$cell)
      if(input$plotType != "Gene-Subset tSNE"){
        # subset of data
        gene.tsne.df <- left_join(all.data.tsne.df %>% filter(cluster %in% chosen.clusters(),sample %in% chosen.samples()),data.frame(cell=colnames(mat)[col.idx],value=mat[row.idx,col.idx]),by=c("cell"="cell"))
        scatter.plot <- plot_ly(marker=list(size=6),type='scatter',mode="markers",color=~gene.tsne.df$value,x=~gene.tsne.df$tSNE1,y=~gene.tsne.df$tSNE2,showlegend=F,colors=colorRamp(color.vec)) %>%
          layout(xaxis=list(title="tSNE1",zeroline=F,showticklabels=F),yaxis=list(title="tSNE2",zeroline=F,showticklabels=F)) %>%
          colorbar(limits=c(min(gene.tsne.df$value,na.rm=T),max(gene.tsne.df$value,na.rm=T)),len=0.4,title="Expression")
        break
      } else{
        subset.genes <- sort(unique(input$subset.genes))
        subset.row.idx <- which(rownames(mat) %in% subset.genes)
        if(!is.null(subset.tsne.map)){
          idx <- which(names(subset.tsne.map) == paste0(paste(subset.row.idx,collapse="_"),":",paste(col.idx,collapse="_")))
          if(length(idx) > 0){
            subset.tsne.df <- subset.tsne.map[[idx]] %>% mutate(value=mat[row.idx,col.idx])
            scatter.plot <- plot_ly(marker=list(size=6),type='scatter',mode="markers",color=~subset.tsne.df$value,x=~subset.tsne.df$tSNE1,y=~subset.tsne.df$tSNE2,showlegend=F,colors=colorRamp(color.vec)) %>%
              layout(xaxis=list(title="tSNE1",zeroline=F,showticklabels=F),yaxis=list(title="tSNE2",zeroline=F,showticklabels=F)) %>%
              colorbar(limits=c(min(subset.tsne.df$value,na.rm=T),max(subset.tsne.df$value,na.rm=T)),len=0.4,title="Expression")
          }
        } else{
          subset.tsne.df <- data.frame(t(mat[subset.row.idx,col.idx]),cell=colnames(mat)[col.idx]) %>% left_join(meta.df %>% filter(cell %in% colnames(mat)[col.idx]) %>% select(cell,cluster),by=c("cell"="cell"))
          tsne.perplexity <- 10*length(subset.row.idx)
          while(tsne.perplexity >= 1){
            set.seed(1)
            tsne.obj <- try(Rtsne::Rtsne(subset.tsne.df %>% select(-cell,-cluster),perplexity=tsne.perplexity),silent=T)
            if(class(tsne.obj)[1] != "try-error"){
              subset.tsne.df <- cbind(subset.tsne.df,data.frame(tsne.obj$Y) %>% rename(tSNE1=X1,tSNE2=X2))
              subset.tsne.map[[length(subset.tsne.map)+1]] <- subset.tsne.df
              names(subset.tsne.map)[length(subset.tsne.map)] <- paste0(paste(subset.row.idx,collapse="_"),":",paste(col.idx,collapse="_"))
              subset.tsne.df <- subset.tsne.df %>% mutate(value=mat[row.idx,col.idx])
              scatter.plot <- plot_ly(marker=list(size=6),type='scatter',mode="markers",color=~subset.tsne.df$value,x=~subset.tsne.df$tSNE1,y=~subset.tsne.df$tSNE2,showlegend=F,colors=colorRamp(color.vec)) %>%
                layout(xaxis=list(title="tSNE1",zeroline=F,showticklabels=F),yaxis=list(title="tSNE2",zeroline=F,showticklabels=F)) %>%
                colorbar(limits=c(min(subset.tsne.df$value,na.rm=T),max(subset.tsne.df$value,na.rm=T)),len=0.4,title="Expression")
            } else{
              tsne.perplexity <- tsne.perplexity-2
            }
          }
        }
      }
      scatter.plot
    }
  })

  output$Embedding <- renderPlotly({
    scatter.plot()
  })

  output$save <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste0("../shiny/",input$gene,".",input$plotType,".pdf")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      plotly::export(scatter.plot(),file=file)
    }
  )
}
```

And here's my `UI` code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Results Explorer"),

  # Sidebar layout with a input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(
    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      ## custom CSS for 3 column layout (used below for mechanics filter options)
      tags$head(
        tags$style(HTML(".multicol {-webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */-moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */column-count: 3;}"))),
      ## use the css, assuming your long list of vars comes from global.R
      wellPanel(tags$div(class="multicol",checkboxGroupInput("samples.choice", "Samples",choices = names(samples.choices),selected="all"))),
      wellPanel(tags$div(class="multicol",checkboxGroupInput("clusters.choice", "Clusters",choices = names(clusters.choices),selected="all"))),

      # select plot type
      selectInput("plotType", "Plot Type", choices = c("tSNE","Gene-Subset tSNE")),

      #in case Gene Subset tSNE was chose select the genes
      conditionalPanel(condition="input.plotType=='Gene-Subset tSNE'",
                       selectizeInput(inputId="subset.genes",label="Subset Genes for tSNE",choices=rownames(mat),selected=rownames(mat)[1],multiple=T)),

      # select gene
      uiOutput("gene"),

      # save plot as html
      downloadButton('save', 'Save as PDF')
    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      # The plot is called Embedding and will be created in ShinyServer part
      plotlyOutput("Embedding")
    )
  )
)


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

It doesn't seem to be updating `subset.tsne.map` and each gene that is selected, even for the same sets of cells and genes, it run `Rtsne` again.

Is it possible to update `subset.tsne.map` with previously selected subsets at all? and if so am I doing it correctly?

Comment: Have you looked at [reactive values](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.1/reactiveValues.html)?

Comment: I see. So I guess that `subset.tsne.map` needs to be a `reactiveValues` and be defined inside the `server` code. And probably there needs to be a `validate` statement that checks if the selected subset already exists in `subset.tsne.map` and if not will run `Rtsne` on the subset selection and will update `subset.tsne.map`. But I'm not sure how to write these parts. The `validate` and `need` examples I see only report an error message if `need` is not met. Any idea?